# Next.JS: Share Usestate Between Parent and Child Components

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, react-hooks

#### The Problem I'm Solving

On a Next.JS page, I'm making many calls to the database. The main page contains all the code for database queries. All child components are client components that allow the user to complete inputs, running the query code from the main page. I want to ensure that the server isn't running more than one instance of a request at a time. I also want the user to know that they have to wait until the server finishes handling the said requests.

The solution is a 'isLoading' useState which is shared between all parent and child components. When the useState is true, all buttons and inputs become inactive on the entire page. Upon a successful or unsuccessful completion of a database request, setIsLoading(false) runs, and all inputs return to normal; awaiting a new request.

#### React's Conflict

React seems to not have a solution for a useState that is global to all parent and child components. I can pass a state change from child to parent by calling a method from the parent function, but I can't pass the state change to all the additional child components within that parent component. I'm getting `TypeError: "isLoading" is read-only`

---

Here is the code that receives that error:

```
useEffect(() => {
  /// Update the isLoading for all children components
  setSections((prevSections) => {
    let newSections = prevSections.map((component, i) => {
      component.props.isLoading = isLoading
      return component;
    });
  
    return newSections;
  });
}, [isLoading])
```

*Note: I've been playing with the code in attempt to get around the "readonly" limitation.*

---

This is what some form elements might look like:

```
<div className="buttons">
  <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Paragraph")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Paragaph'}</button>
  <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Ordered List")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Ordered List'}</button>
  <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Image")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Image'}</button>
</div>
```

---

Parent components might have many child components. Those child components then may become parents for many more components. **The page is generated on render using components - based on the database. I need to communicate the useState between all the dynamic child and parent components whenever the state is changed IN ANY component.**

#### Global Parent Component Code:

```
'use client'
import React, { ReactComponentElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ArticleSection from "./ArticleSection";
import { Article, ListItem, Media, OrderedList, Paragraph, Section, SectionItem } from "@/lib/interface/dbArticle";
import SectionMedia from "./SectionMedia";
import AutoTextarea from "../AutoTextarea";

type props = {
  className?: string;
  article: Article;
  loadSections?: Section[];
  loadParagraphs?: Paragraph[][];
  loadMedias?: Media[][];
  loadOrderedLists?: OrderedList[][];
  loadListItems?: ListItem[][][];
  CreateNewSection: (articleID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewParagraph: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewMedia: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewOrderedList: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewListItem: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteSection: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteParagraph: (paragraphID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteMedia: (mediaID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteOrderedList: (orderedListID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteListItem: (listItemID: number) => Promise<string>;
  UpdateTitle: (table: number, id: number, title: string) => Promise<string>;
  UpdateContent: (table: number, id: number, content: string) => Promise<string>;
}

const ArticleSectionManager : React.FC<props> = ({className = '', article, loadSections = [], loadParagraphs = [], loadMedias = [], loadOrderedLists = [], loadListItems = [], CreateNewSection, CreateNewParagraph, CreateNewMedia, CreateNewOrderedList, CreateNewListItem, DeleteSection, DeleteParagraph, DeleteMedia, DeleteOrderedList, DeleteListItem, UpdateTitle, UpdateContent}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [sections, setSections] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState("")
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File>()
  useEffect(() => {
    let loadSectionItems: SectionItem[][] = [];
    loadSections?.map((section, i) => {
      /// Convert tables into a generic type
      loadSectionItems[i] = [];
      let tracker = 0;
      if (loadParagraphs[i] != undefined) {
        loadParagraphs[i].map((paragraph, l) => {
          loadSectionItems[i][tracker++] = {id: paragraph.id, section_id: paragraph.section_id, place: paragraph.place, type: 1}
        })
      }
      if (loadMedias[i] != undefined) {
        loadMedias[i].map((media, l) => {
          loadSectionItems[i][tracker++] = {id: media.id, section_id: media.section_id, place: media.place, type: 2}
        })  
      }
      if (loadOrderedLists[i] != undefined) {
        loadOrderedLists[i].map((list, l) => {
          loadSectionItems[i][tracker++] = {id: list.id, section_id: list.section_id, place: list.place, type: 3}
        })
      }
      /// Reorder sectionItems based on 'place' variable
      loadSectionItems[i].sort((a, b) => a.place - b.place);
      const newSection = <ArticleSection key={section.id}
        section={section} loadSectionItems={loadSectionItems[i]} 
        loadParagraphs={loadParagraphs[i]} loadMedias={loadMedias[i]} 
        loadOrderedLists={loadOrderedLists[i]} loadListItems={loadListItems[i]} 
        isLoading={isLoading} 
        setIsLoading={(bool) => {setIsLoading(bool)}}
        CreateNewParagraph={CreateNewParagraph}
        CreateNewMedia={CreateNewMedia}
        CreateNewOrderedList={CreateNewOrderedList}
        CreateNewListItem={CreateNewListItem}
        DeleteSection={HandleDeleteSection}
        DeleteParagraph={DeleteParagraph}
        DeleteMedia={DeleteMedia}
        DeleteOrderedList={DeleteOrderedList}
        DeleteListItem={DeleteListItem}
        UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle}
        UpdateContent={UpdateContent}
      />;
      setSections((prevSections) => [...prevSections, newSection]);
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    /// Update the isLoading for all children components
    // setSections((prevSections) => {
    //   let newSections = prevSections.map((component, i) => {
    //     component.props.isLoading = isLoading
    //     return component;
    //   });
  
    //   return newSections;
    // });
  }, [isLoading])

  const HandleNewSectionClick = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const sectionRtn: string[] = (await CreateNewSection(article.id)).split('|,');
      if (sectionRtn[0] == '0') return
      const section: Section = JSON.parse(sectionRtn[1])[0]
      const newSection = <ArticleSection key={section.id} section={section} 
        isLoading={isLoading} 
        setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
        CreateNewParagraph={CreateNewParagraph}
        CreateNewMedia={CreateNewMedia}
        CreateNewOrderedList={CreateNewOrderedList}
        CreateNewListItem={CreateNewListItem}
        DeleteSection={HandleDeleteSection}
        DeleteParagraph={DeleteParagraph}
        DeleteMedia={DeleteMedia}
        DeleteOrderedList={DeleteOrderedList}
        DeleteListItem={DeleteListItem}
        UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle}
        UpdateContent={UpdateContent}
      />; // Create a new ArticleSection element
      setSections((prevSections) => [...prevSections, newSection]);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.reponse?.data);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const HandleDeleteSection = async (sectionID: number) => {
    const rtn = await DeleteSection(sectionID)
    setSections((prevSections) => {
      const updatedSections = prevSections.filter((item) => item.key != sectionID);
  
      return updatedSections;
    });

    return rtn
  };

  const HandleContentChange = async (content: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await UpdateContent(5, article.id, content);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.reponse?.data);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      if (!selectedFile) return;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", selectedFile);
      // const { data } = await UploadImage(formData)
      // console.log(data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.reponse?.data);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`SectionMedia ${className}`}>
        <h3>Article Header Image:</h3>
        <input type="file"
        hidden
        onChange={({target}) => {
          if (target.files) {
            const file = target.files[0];
            setSelectedImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            setSelectedFile(file);
          }
        }} />
        <button className="btn-upload" disabled={isLoading}>
          <div className="text">{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Upload Image'}</div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="InputGroup">
        <label htmlFor="">Article Title:</label>
        <input type="text" onBlur={async (event) => {setIsLoading(true);await UpdateTitle(5, article.id, event.target.value);setIsLoading(false);}} defaultValue={article.title} disabled={isLoading} />
      </div>
      <div className="InputGroup">
        <label htmlFor="">Article Summary:</label>
        <AutoTextarea pretext={article.content} Trigger={HandleContentChange} />
      </div>
      {sections.map((section) => section)}
      <button onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleNewSectionClick()}} disabled={isLoading}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'New Section'}</button>
      <button>Publish Article</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default ArticleSectionManager
```

#### First Child Component Code (the current one I'm testing):

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TitleButton from "./TitleButton";
import SectionParagraph from "./SectionParagraph";
import SectionList from "./SectionList";
import SectionMedia from "./SectionMedia";
import SvgDelete from "@/components/svg/SvgDelete";
import { ListItem, Media, OrderedList, Paragraph, Section, SectionItem } from "@/lib/interface/dbArticle";

type props = {
  className?: string;
  section: Section;
  loadSectionItems?: SectionItem[];
  loadParagraphs?: Paragraph[];
  loadMedias?: Media[];
  loadOrderedLists?: OrderedList[];
  loadListItems?: ListItem[][];
  isLoading: boolean;
  setIsLoading: (newValue: boolean) => void;
  CreateNewParagraph: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewMedia: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewOrderedList: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  CreateNewListItem: (OrderedListID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteSection: (sectionID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteParagraph: (paragraphID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteMedia: (mediaID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteOrderedList: (orderedListID: number) => Promise<string>;
  DeleteListItem: (listItemID: number) => Promise<string>;
  UpdateTitle: (table: number, id: number, title: string) => Promise<string>;
  UpdateContent: (table: number, id: number, content: string) => Promise<string>;
}

const ArticleSection : React.FC<props> = ({className = '', section, loadSectionItems = [], loadParagraphs = [], loadMedias = [], loadOrderedLists = [], loadListItems = [], isLoading, setIsLoading, CreateNewParagraph, CreateNewMedia, CreateNewOrderedList, CreateNewListItem, DeleteSection, DeleteParagraph, DeleteMedia, DeleteOrderedList, DeleteListItem, UpdateTitle, UpdateContent}) => {
  const [sectionItems, setSectionItems] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let numOrderedLists: number = 0;
    loadSectionItems?.map((sectionItem, index) => {
      let newElement: JSX.Element;
      switch (sectionItem.type) {
        case 1:
          newElement = <SectionParagraph key={sectionItem.place} paragraph={loadParagraphs.find(item => item.id === sectionItem.id)} onDelete={() => handleDelete(sectionItem.place)} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />;
          break;
        case 2:
          newElement = <SectionMedia key={sectionItem.place} media={loadMedias.find(item => item.id === sectionItem.id)} onDelete={() => handleDelete(sectionItem.place)} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />;
          break;
        case 3:
          newElement = <SectionList key={sectionItem.place} orderedList={loadOrderedLists.find(item => item.id === sectionItem.id)} loadListItems={loadListItems[numOrderedLists]} onDelete={() => handleDelete(sectionItem.place)} CreateNewListItem={CreateNewListItem} DeleteListItem={DeleteListItem} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />;
          numOrderedLists++;
          break;
      }
      setSectionItems((prevSections) => [...prevSections, newElement]);

    })
  }, [])

  const HandleButtonClick = async (elementType: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let newElement: JSX.Element;

    switch (elementType) {
      case "Paragraph":
        const paragraphRtn: string[] = (await CreateNewParagraph(section.id)).split('|,');
        if (paragraphRtn[0] != '1') {console.log(paragraphRtn[1]);break;}
        const paragraph: Paragraph = JSON.parse(paragraphRtn[1])[0];
        loadSectionItems[(paragraph.place - 1)] = {id: paragraph.id, section_id: paragraph.section_id, place: paragraph.place, type: 1}
        newElement = <SectionParagraph key={paragraph.place} paragraph={paragraph} onDelete={() => handleDelete(paragraph.place)} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />; // Create a new ArticleSection element
        break;
      case "Image":
        const mediaRtn: string[] = (await CreateNewMedia(section.id)).split('|,');
        if (mediaRtn[0] != '1') {console.log(mediaRtn[1]);break;}
        const media: Media = JSON.parse(mediaRtn[1])[0];
        loadSectionItems[(media.place - 1)] = {id: media.id, section_id: media.section_id, place: media.place, type: 2}
        newElement = <SectionMedia key={media.place} media={media} onDelete={() => handleDelete(media.place)} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />;
        break;
      case "Ordered List":
        const orderedListRtn: string[] = (await CreateNewOrderedList(section.id)).split('|,');
        if (orderedListRtn[0] != '1') {console.log(orderedListRtn[1]);break;}
        let orderedList: OrderedList = JSON.parse(orderedListRtn[1])[0];
        loadSectionItems[(orderedList.place - 1)] = {id: orderedList.id, section_id: orderedList.section_id, place: orderedList.place, type: 3}
        newElement = <SectionList key={orderedList.place} orderedList={orderedList} onDelete={() => handleDelete(orderedList.place)} CreateNewListItem={CreateNewListItem} DeleteListItem={DeleteListItem} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle} UpdateContent={UpdateContent} />;
        break;
    }

    setSectionItems((prevSections) => [...prevSections, newElement]);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const handleDelete = async (place: number) => {
    const sectionPlace: number = place - 1;
    switch (loadSectionItems[sectionPlace].type) {
      case 1:
        await DeleteParagraph(loadSectionItems[sectionPlace].id)
        break;
      case 2:
        await DeleteMedia(loadSectionItems[sectionPlace].id)
        break;
      case 3:
        await DeleteOrderedList(loadSectionItems[sectionPlace].id)
        break;
    }
    setSectionItems((prevSections) => {
      let newSections = prevSections.filter((item, i) => i !== (place - 1)); // Remove the component at the specified index
      // Update the keys and onDelete props for the remaining components
      newSections = newSections.map((component, i) => {
        if (loadSectionItems[i].place > place) {
          // Update the key to be the same as the 'place' row in database
          const newKey: number = loadSectionItems[i].place - 1
          component.key = newKey
          if (typeof component.props.onDelete === 'function') {
            component.props.onDelete = () => {handleDelete(newKey)}
            // return React.cloneElement(component, { key: i, onDelete: () => handleDelete(i) });
          }
        }
        
        return component;
      });
  
      return newSections;
    });
  };

  const HandleDeleteSection = async () => {
    const rtn = await DeleteSection(section.id);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={`ArticleSection ${className}`}>
      <SvgDelete onDelete={HandleDeleteSection} />
      <h2>Section:</h2>
      <TitleButton pretext={section.title} table={0} id={section.id} UpdateTitle={UpdateTitle}/>
      {sectionItems.map((section) => section)}
      <div className="buttons">
        <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Paragraph")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Paragaph'}</button>
        <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Ordered List")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Ordered List'}</button>
        <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : HandleButtonClick("Image")}}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Image'}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ArticleSection
```